# How to serve previously created Jupyter Notebook on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, gcp-notebook

I have a previously created jupyter notebook that I'd like to run on the Google Cloud Platform.

I currently have a notebook instance running on a GCP VM and it works fine.  I was also able to create a storage bucket and upload all dataset and notebook files to the bucket.  However, these files don't show up in the Jupyter Notebook directory tree.  I know I can access the dataset files using something like...

```
client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.getbucket('name-of-bucket')
blob = storage.Blob( 'diretory/to/files', bucket )
fid = BytesIO(blob.downloadas_string())
```

But I'm not sure how to actually serve up a notebook file to use, and I really don't feel like copying and pasting all my previous work.

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.  You can upload directly from within the Jupyter Notebook and bypass the bucket if desired (the icon with the up arrow).

[Jupyter Notebook upload icon image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BnZS.png)

The only issue with this is you can't upload folders, so zip the folder first then upload it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jupyter Lab's [git extension](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-git) to host your Notebooks in GitHub and pull them from there.

Fyi, if you use GCP's [AI Platform Notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks/) you'll get a pre-configured Jupyter environment with many ML/DL libraries pre-installed.  That git extension will  be pre-installed as well.

Comment: Hi @Zain Rizvi.  I'm having an issue actually getting a GCP AI Platform Notebook to run on the GPU.  Any chance you could take a look?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57140254/google-cloud-ai-platform-notebook-instance-wont-use-gpu-with-jupyter